# Paperclip gem with Ruby IO File Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm trying to attach images to an ActiveRecord object with the Paperclip gem. However, I'm trying to attach images, not from a form, but from a script that looks for images in a folder.

Here is my code

```
file = File.open("some_image.jpg", "r")

my_object.image = file
my_object.save

file.close
```

The script runs successfully (no errors). However, when I check the website, the images are not showing up. The images were apparently never attached.

I've looked through the documentation, but wasn't able to find anything that solved the problem.

Also, here is `MyObject` class

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Attachments 
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `.save!` which will tell you if the model was actually saved? You should also be able to just do `File.open("some_image.jpg", "r") {|f| my_object.update! }`.

Comment: @max Nope didn't work. I tried some over stuff too, like passing a block to File.open and writing `my_object.image = f.read` but that didn't work either.

Comment: @max After days of trying to figure it out, I finally got it and you're comment helped. Thanks!